# What is the best/fastest way to echo duplicate array values and their count in php

Tags: php, arrays, echo, array-filter

I need your advice if there is a better (and faster) way to output duplicate array values and their count in php.

Currently, I am doing it with the below code:

The initial input is always a text string like this:

```
$text = "a,b,c,d,,,e,a,b,c,d,f,g,"; //Note the comma at the end
```

Then I get the unique array values:

```
$arrText = array_unique(explode(',',rtrim($text,',')));
```

Then I count the duplicate values in the array (excluding the empty ones):

```
$cntText = array_count_values(array_filter(explode(',', $text)));
```

And finally I echo the array values and their count with a loop inside a loop:

```
foreach($arrText as $text){
       echo $text;
       foreach($cntText as $cnt_text=>$count){
              if($cnt_text == $text){
                    echo " (".$count.")";
              }
}
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to output the unique values and their count without using a loop inside a loop.

Currently I have chosen this approach because:

1. My input is always a text string
2. The text string contains empty values and has a comma at the end
3. I need to echo only non empty values

Let me know your expert advices!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your code to print the values a lot shorter (Also I wrote other things a bit shorter):

You don't need `rtrim()` or `array_unique()`, you only need `explode()` and with `array_filter()` you take care of the empty values. Then just use `array_count_values()` and loop through the values.

```
<?php

    $text = "a,b,c,d,,,e,a,b,c,d,f,g,";
    $filtered = array_filter(explode(",", $text));
    $countes = array_count_values($filtered);

    foreach($countes as $k => $v)
        echo "$k ($v)";

?>
```

output:

```
a (2)b (2)c (2)d (2)e (1)f (1)g (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to make two arrays as `array_count_values` keys are the value of the text.

```
$myArray = array_count_values(array_filter(explode(',',$text)));
foreach($myArray as $key => $value){
    echo $key . ' (' . $value . ')';
}
```